# Using Checkpoint saving with train_on_batch in Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm training my data in batches using `train_on_batch`, but it seems `train_on_batch` doesn't have an option to use callbacks, which seems to be a requirement to use checkpoints.

I can't use `model.fit` as that seems to require I load all of my data into memory.

`model.fit_generator` is giving me strange problems (like hanging at end of an epoch).

Here is the example from Keras API docs showing the use of `ModelCheckpoint`:

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=784, kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/tmp/weights.hdf5', verbose=1, 
                               save_best_only=True)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, 
          verbose=0, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

Comment: As you stated: You can't use model.fit if all the data is too big for your memory. So focus on what's wrong with model.fit_generator. Can you explain and show this strange behavior?

Comment: @dennis-ec  There was a bug with `ImageDataGenerator` in 2.09 which got fixed via a update (I opened an issue with the Keras team).  No problems anymore. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you train on each batch manually, you can do whatever you want at any #epoch(#batch). No need to use callback, just call `model.save` or `model.save_weights`.

Comment: and then how can I load the saved model and start from there?

Comment: Just load the model or weight and run the training process. This will start the training from the previous parameters you saved.